сохранение строковых данных
Eсть следующая ситуация:

список строк1 (TStringList), число строк от 1000 до 2000000, формат строки 665:687686:12334456(это пример), где : разделитель
список строк2 (TStringList), число строк от 0 до 255, формат строки 12334456(это пример)
цикл FOR список1, где отделяется третий параметр (12334456), внутри цикл FOR где выводится строка, если строки в циклах совпадают, тогда строка1 (665:687686:12334456) перезаписывается в хранилище строк с именем третьего параметра (12334456)
таким образом может возникнуть до 256 хранилищ с числом строк от 1000 до 140000 строк в каждом.
в общем это раздел одного большого массива строк на некоторое количество массивом по заданному параметру (список строк2)

вопрос: на основе чего можно сделать такое хранилище строк? TListBox? динамический многомерный массив? что то еще? надо учесть быстродействие, по максимуму необходимо.

TListBox как хранилище, очевидно, ужасная идея. Если вы знаете, что хранилищ обычно 256, то просто статический массив [0..255] с TList<string>. TStringList не самая лучшая идея, т.к. ле дополнительно к каждой строке хранит по ссылке на TObject, что может быть излишним.

TListBox ну да это просто опечатка, имелось ввиду TList



статический массив [0..255] с TList.  вообще число хранилищ заранее неизвестно но не более 256.  а скорость сборки массивов в сравнении с "динамический многомерный массив" ?



что быстрее будет заполнятся строками TArray или array of string(динамический)

Хранилище собирается один раз, и используется много раз? Что будете делать с этим хранилищем дальше? Пока смотрится как словарь TDictionary<string, TStringList>

одно хранилище - список отфильтрованных строк, по параметру. число хранилищ - динамическое, зависит от список строк2
список строк1 и список строк2 тоже зависят, каждый раз другие. просто в стенде оне хранятся в TStringList. ну для удобства. вообще нужно что то более быстрок. может динамический массив. но это потом, вначале нужно собрать всю схему обработки картинки

Более быстрое для чего - извлекать набор строк по ключу? создавать это хранилище? Пока что словарь или сортированный по ключу список/массив подходят (trie пока не упоминаю, для небольшого количества ключей, может, и  не понадобится). Вообще толковое описание реальной задачи принесло бы больше пользы.


Не совсем понятно зачем второй цикл, ведь у TStringList есть метод IndexOf() -- можно сразу проверить наличие искомой строки. 2. В хранилище может быть несколько строк для одного ключа? Можно использовать что-то вроде TDictionary<string, TList>. 3. Я бы смотрел в сторону in-memory database. В Delphi есть LocalSQL


begin
LstCls := TStringList.Create;
LstHWColor := TStringList.Create;
LstHWColor.Text := Memo1.Text; // список строк1
LstCls.Text := Memo2.Text; // список строк2
for I := 0 to LstHWColor - 1 do
begin
pxColorData := (LstHWColor[I]);
ColorData := выделение(pxColorData);
for J := 0 to LstCls.Count - 1 do
begin
if (ColorData = LstCls[J]) then
begin
// вот тут надо сохранить массивы строк с именем LstCls[J]
end;
end;
end;
end;

не понял как тут код форматировать

@Pcrepair, если я правильно понял, то вместо второго цикла можно написать if LstCls.IndexOf(ColorData) >= 0 then // save

Не нужно код в комментариях писать. Если это относится к тому же вопросу (а не похоже) - редактируйте вопрос, иначе задавайте новый вопрос.
